# Django ManyToManyField as multiset

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, multiset

Is there any way how to store the same object in m2m field multiple times?

Let's say I have the following models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Inventory(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Items', blank=True)
```

And I create some instances

```
>>> inventory = Inventory()
>>> inventory.save()

>>> item1 = Item(name='Item 1')
>>> item1.save()

>>> item2 = Item(name='Item 2')
>>> item2.save()
```

Now I want to add those instances of item to the inventory multiple times.

```
>>> inventory.items.add(item1)
>>> inventory.items.add(item2)

>>> inventory.items.all()
[<Item: Item 1>, <Item: Item 2>]

>>> inventory.items.add(item1)

>>> inventory.items.all()
[<Item: Item 1>, <Item: Item 2>]
```

So ManyToManyField works like a set, is there any way to achieve the behavior of a multiset?

Comment: Related cross site: [Modeling an inventory system in SQL](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116996)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing `Item`'s in your inventory, you can store `InventoryItem`'s

```
class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory)
```

The idea is you introduce a middle class that handles the quantity for you, as well as potentially other things like should the item be stackable.

The only alternative I can think of is to duplicate an item object and then store both of these in the inventory - which may or may not be better for your use case

Comment: Oh, I thought that I would have to do some middle class but I hoped I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Zoli - Like I said, you can avoid it by duplicating the item object, or potentially some other black magic such as using an `ArrayField`. But neither of them seem very good alternatives to me. I'd imagine at some point you'll want some items to be stackable also (i.e Coins or similar), assuming you're making some kind of game